# 403 Forbidden issue with ShopifyAPI::RecurringApplicationCharge api

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api

Currently, we are using Custom App for Shopify application development. We are facing 403 Forbidden issue (ActiveResource::ForbiddenAccess (Failed. Response code = 403. Response message = Forbidden)) when we are trying to hit ShopifyAPI::RecurringApplicationCharge.current api. So, anyone could you please let us know what we need to do here to resolve this.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that with Custom App. Reference: [here](https://shopify.dev/concepts/apps#custom-apps)

```
Custom app: An app custom built for a single client.

Capabilities of a custom app:
- Limited to installation on one merchant store
- Not reviewed by Shopify
- Can’t be converted into a sales channel
- Can’t use the Billing API to charge merchants
```

So if you want to use Billing API change your app to public app.